# Error when using order by in hive table built with Avro

Tags: hive, hdfs, avro

i have created twitter table to store twitter data using AvroSerDe using the following code

```
CREATE TABLE twitter
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT
     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
  TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='file:///home/siva/TwitterDataAvroSchema.avsc') ;
```

my table was created successfully, when i run `SELECT * FROM twitter ;` it works normally but when i try to execute this query with `ORDER BY`

```
select user_screen_name as name , user_location as location ,user_followers_count as count
from twitter 
order by count desc
limit 5;
```

it shows the following error :

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

but when i try to run another query with `ORDER BY` on another table created in normal way it works .
the full log file :

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.doNextWithExceptionHandler(HadoopShimsSecure.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.next(HadoopShimsSecure.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.doNext(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.doNext(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.doNextWithExceptionHandler(HadoopShimsSecure.java:229)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.next(DataFileStream.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroGenericRecordReader.next(AvroGenericRecordReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroGenericRecordReader.next(AvroGenericRecordReader.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:360)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:128)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readString(BinaryDecoder.java:259)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readString(ResolvingDecoder.java:201)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readString(GenericDatumReader.java:363)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readString(GenericDatumReader.java:355)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:157)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:193)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.next(DataFileStream.java:233)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.next(DataFileStream.java:220)
    ... 18 more
```